# Redefining contentsline with hyperref loaded

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

The latex code below fails to compile at the 2nd round of pdflatex. If I remove the hyperref package it compiles fine, however if it's there, it fails to compile and complains giving this error

> (./master.out) (./master.out) (./master.toc)
>   [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex /updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
>   (./master.lot ! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.  
>                   \par  l.3 \contentsline
>                     {table}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces My table's caption...

How can I sove it?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\mempostaddchaptertotochook{%
  \addchaptertoloft{lof}%
  \addchaptertoloft{lot}%
}
\def\addchaptertoloft#1{% 
   \addtocontents{#1}{% 
     \protect\xcontentsline{chapter} 
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter\protect\nopagebreak\protect\vspace{1ex}}{}}}
\makeatletter
\def\xcontentsline#1#2#3{\@ifnextchar\contentsline 
  {\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}{}} 
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{My table's caption}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c} 
        \hline
        column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
        \hline
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this post at all. Please phrase this as as _question_ (to which you may then post separately an _answer_)

Comment: Ok, I'll do it.

Comment: With `hyperref`, `\contentsline` needs five arguments, not three. So adding `{}{}` after `{#3}` will do.

Comment: I found that adding the following solved the problem    \def\xcontentsline#1#2#3{\@ifnextchar\contentsline 
  {\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{}}{}}

Comment: @redcrash Maybe it's sufficient to edit my answer to the other question to make it more complete and forget about this one.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, I'm a noob here... I'll take that path next time :)